# Is there a cleaner way in objective-c to cap a value between two numbers?

Tags: objective-c

Is there a more concise way to write the following code?

```
if (myValue > 100) 
  myValue = 100;
if (myValue < 0) 
  myValue = 0;
```

Thanks in advance for your wisdom!

Comment: There are a dozen variations of the same thing.  Nothing magical.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `MAX` and `MIN`, though it's not necessarily as clear.

```
myValue = MAX(MIN(myValue, 100), 0);
```

Comment: I agree, though I still like that better than the four-liner above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
myValue = (myValue > 100) ? 100 : myValue;
myValue = (myValue < 0) ? 0 : myValue;
```

or

```
myValue = (myValue > 100) ? 100 : ((myValue < 0) ? 0 : myValue);
```

of course I would use `MIN`/`MAX` even if you do 2 lines.

maybe even

```
#define MINMAX(_min_,_max_,_n_) (MAX(MIN(_n_, _max_), _min_))
```